# android SDK missing in D directory

Tags: android, ionic-framework, sdk

I want to download SDK for android 4.41 without download Android Studio.
This is my steps:

1. download zip file from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-3859397.zip
2. extract the folder and locate it at D:/sdk-tools/
3. refer to this link https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html , I at D:/sdk-tools/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-16"
4. It downloaded, but can't find any SDK when I use genymotion,adb to locate the SDK.
   [image][image]
5. I refer to C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Android but also can't find any SDK.

I need to have the SDK in D drive as my C drive is running out of space. I want to use genymotion to debug my ionic code.

Which part of my works is incorrect as I can't find the SDK?

Comment: open sdk manager you should see the path at the top

Comment: @RonTLV I am using command line. It does not show the SDK manager box so that I can select the API I want. How to do download sdk manager?

Answer (score 0):

select just platform tools d:\ Sdk\platform-tools\, and set path variable for adb , if you open cmd and type adb to see if you working.

Comment: What is path varibale? can elaborate more?

Comment: in platform tools folder you must have adb.exe  https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10

Comment: I just set as you said, it is still unable to find the SDK in genymotion. http://i.imgur.com/IagzGJF.png

Comment: in that folder do you have adb , fastboot ... ? (i am on linux for 2 years) search a folder with adb.exe and fastboot.exe

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I use command `sdkmanager "platforms;android-16"`, is that will install adb,fastboot?

Comment: yes but you must cd the right folder . better download adb tools from the internet , or search on sdk folder for adb.exe

Comment: I can't find adb.exe. It should be downloaded directly from `sdkmanager "platforms;android-16"`, correct?

Comment: adb.exe is by genymotion. How shall I proceed to locate external API? I need to use for debug